# MySQL having three joins that needs form in one join

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to join tables to see which product is cheaper in terms of their continent. i have provided more detail below.

I have the following four tables:

```html
country   Product1 Product2 Product3
Austria      0.01    0.011    0.018
Cuba         0.15    0.015    0.012
Angola       0.17    0.017    0.019
Benin        0.84    0.015    0.025
Belize       0.24    0.019    0.018
where table name is PriceComparison

Code  name         continent_code 
AD    Andorra      EU
AF    Afghanistan  AS
AI    Anguilla     NA 
AL    Albania      EU
AO    Angola       AF
table name is countries

Id  Name     countrycode 
1   Albania      AL
2   Algeria      DZ
3   Andorra      AD
4   Angola       AO    
5   Austria      AT 
table name is CountryList

code   name 
AF   Africa 
AN   Antarctica
AS   Asia 
EU   Europe
NA   North America
OC   Ocenia
SA South America 
table name is continents
```

Code  name         continent_code 
AD    Andorra      EU
AF    Afghanistan  AS
AI    Anguilla     NA 
AL    Albania      EU
AO    Angola       AF
table name is countries

Id  Name     countrycode 
1   Albania      AL
2   Algeria      DZ
3   Andorra      AD
4   Angola       AO
5   Austria      AT 
table name is CountryList

code   name 
AF   Africa 
AN   Antarctica
AS   Asia 
EU   Europe
NA   North America
OC   Ocenia
SA South America 
table name is continents

I need to update my PriceComparison with all the other tables i have. The objective here is to see which continent we are cheaper in terms of our products. Product1 is my product. Product1's price needs to be compared with product2's price and again product1's price needs to be compared to product3's price in terms of where my product is cheaper per continent.

Can someone assist with this query?

Tried so far:

```
select countries.continent_code, 
       continents.code, 
       CountryList.countrycode, 
       countries.code, 
       PriceComaprison.country, 
       CountryList.name 
from CountryList as CL 
inner join countries 
  on countries.continent_code = continents.code 
inner join CL 
  on CL.countrycode = countries.code 
inner join PriceComparison 
  on PriceComparison.country = CL.name
```

sample data:

countries: code (AS, AI,AO, BB,CA) name (the actual country name - eg.America Samao) continent_code (OC,NA,AN - the actual continent_code of the country)

CountryList table: id Name countrycode

continents: code name

Comment: note that below is different column names which i have separated now with a comma 

countries: code, name, continent_code

CountryList table: id, Name, countrycode

continents: code, name

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected output. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried:



select
countries.continent_code, 
continents.code, 
CountryList.countrycode,
countries.code,
PriceComaprison.country,
CountryList.name
from CountryList as CL
inner join countries on
countries.continent_code = continents.code
inner join CL on
CL.countrycode = countries.code
inner join PriceComparison on
PriceComparison.country = CL.name;

Comment: you can edit your question instead of commenting.

Comment: CountryList: 

id (1,2,3,4,5)
Name (the country name)
countrycode (the country code, AF, AL, DZ)

Comment: continents:

code (the code of the continent, AF,AN,AS ect)
name(continent name - Africa, Antarctica, Asia ect)

Comment: countries:

code (the actual country code AS,AI ect)
name (Country name) 
continent_name(the actual content of a particular country, OC,NA,AN ect)

Comment: PriceComparison:

country -  (the actual country name)
product1 (cost of product)
product2 (cost of product)
product3 (cost of product)

Comment: Your "sample" data is not really useful. Please provide for each table, sample records with values for all the columns. Then provide the output you expect for that data. NB: the question is not clear. I for one do not understand the meaning of "where the continent is cheaper". Including the literal desired output based on sample data will clarify things.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Amend your question accordingly using the EDIT button provided. Please avoid using the comments section to augment your question.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry i am new to this. i will compile something for you. also i am not sure how the query should look like because mine is incorrect but i can try to explain this better.

Comment: We know. It's why we make these kinds of comments

Comment: @trincot i have edit the comment - please can you have see if this is better for you?

Comment: @D.JLM, I don't really see any change to the specification of sample and desired output. Take [this simple question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033601/write-a-query-to-get-desired-sql-table-output) as example. Please provide such sample data for all your input table, and add a final "table" list the desired output for that sample.

Comment: @trincot thank you for this suggestion - it helped and makes sense. how would you be able to see what i have done? I can show you the link below where i made the changes: Does this need to be approved first, before one can see it on my question posted?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17328380

Comment: Oh boy, you are trying to modify the other question I referred you to!! That is not what you should do. Edit your own question here (use the `edit` link below the question). Don't worry, the modification to the other question will be rejected after a few people have reviewed it.

Comment: @trincot - is the above better? :) 

thank you for assisting

Comment: It is a good start, but the data is not consistent. You need to work a bit on a good sample so that every record has connected records in reference tables. For example, the first table lists Austria, but that country does not occur in `countries`. This is just one example. A sample is not just taking the first 5 records from your tables; it means making a small representation of data that makes sense. Additionally, you should **add** a list that represents the exact output you expect (in the form of a table) corresponding to the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This query will show the average price of each product per continent, if you want the smallest price per continent use MIN() instead of AVG()

```
SELECT con.code, 
   AVG(p.product1),
   AVG(p.product2),
   AVG(p.product3)
FROM PriceComparison p 
    JOIN countries c ON p.country = c.name 
    JOIN continents con ON con.code = c.continent_code
GROUP BY con.code
```

Comment: i have tried this, but it gives me the below error of the CL (countrylist) alias:

.
.
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM CountryList AS CL  INNER JOIN countries     ON countries.continent_code = c' at line 6

Comment: @D.JLM Just remove the comma after the last selected column. Here: `AVG(PC.product3),` and then it should work.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri still not working - gives an error of Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'continents.code' in 'field list' . The table(continents) exists with the code (column) in, but not sure why it's not working.
I need to update my PriceComparison with all the other tables i have. The objective here is to see which continent we are cheaper in terms of our products. Product1 is my product. Product1's price needs to be compared with product2's price and again product1's price needs to be compared to product3's price in terms of where my product is cheaper per continent.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri because continents.code is in the select shouldn't it also be in the from as well? not sure why this is not working,

Comment: My inner join on is correct that i know - but maybe there where i say join countries, join,CL,join PriceComaprison is not in the correct order ect?

Comment: is there someone that can assist please?

Comment: @RigertaDemiri can you maybe have a look at this?

Comment: @D.JLM Checking it again, this query doesn't seem to give you what you need but also what you need it not really clear.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri - thank  you for the reply, Let's ignore what i have tried. From the tables i have provided. I only need to see where product 1 is cheaper than the other products in terms of continents. Only thing i need to see is where product1 is cheaper than the other products, but not by country but by continent. The tables which i have provided needs to be joined on the PriceComparison table,

Comment: @RigertaDemiri because the PriceComparison table is listed with countries and i need to know in the PriceComparison table which product is cheaper in terms of product1. In order to do this i need to join all the other tables on the PriceComparion at the end. Will you be able to assist and does this make sense?

Comment: What would be then your expected result, from the data you have provided in your question?

Comment: @RigertaDemiri Hi Rigerta - thank you so much for assisting. This works perfectly - i will just amend the query with another inner join. thank  you so much

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you explained in the comments, this could be close to what you need:

```
select con.code continenct_code, con.name as continent, product1, Product2, product3
from PriceComparison p join countries c on p.country = c.name 
                       join continents con on con.code = c.continent_code
where Product1 < Product2  and  Product1 < Product3
```

However, the sample data you have provided is not correct. As it is already mentioned in the comments to your question, there are countries in the `PriceComparison` table that do not exist in the `Countries` table-if you run this with your real data I would assume this should work.

I did modify a little your data and you can check it [here](http://rextester.com/KKTDS83779).